# Does Each FireBase Cloud Function Creates its own copy of all the code written in the Nodejs function Application?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Suppose if I have **100 functions (50 functions.https.onCall and 50 functions.https.onRequest)** in having 40 .ts files in my FireBase Function Project . When I upload these 100 functions Does  with each function separate copy of all the 40 .ts files created ? Because when I open any function in Google Cloud Functions Console all the files show with each functions ?

Then how to write cloud functions so that same code does not repeated multiple times in each cloud function ?

Answer (score 0):

> When I upload these 100 functions Does with each function separate copy of all the 40 .ts files created?

Yes.

> Then how to write cloud functions so that same code does not repeated multiple times in each cloud function?

If you're using the Firebase CLI, you will need a different project space for each one, and deploy them each with a different command.  But that's typically not worthwhile, as there are no typical problems that result from having code duplicated.

Comment: Then Each Google Cloud Function contains the code of all 100 cloud functions ? Is this not taking un necessary space with each cloud function ? What is the benefit from passing all the un necessary code with all the function ?

Comment: The space used in the server image doesn't cost you anything and it doesn't impact performance all that much.  You'd need to be storing many megabytes of extra data in order to see any sort of measurable drop in performance, and that would likely only be for cold starts.  But it's up to you to measure and decide if you want to take action.